# Upgrade Rails project from 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started writing an app in 3.0 when it came out and now that I have pulled my 3.0 project into a Rails 3.1 environment, I'm curious how I could upgrade my app to be able to benefit from the features in Rails 3.1 (namely the CSS and Javascript configuration). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have followed this guide bellow in the past

http://webtempest.com/upgrade-rails-3-to-3-1/

Answer (score 0):

So I took from this you've already upgraded it and are just wondering what the new features are? You already named two of the biggest ones, SCSS and javascript (the asset pipeline). There's a ton of other things as well. Something I use a lot is the has_secure_password feature. Here's a link with some additional information from the release. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/5/22/rails-3-1-release-candidate